# 500 Internal Server Error when run perl file and no access to command line

Tags: linux, command-line, perl, http-status-code-500

I'm a newbie with Perl. I've created a simple file `test.pl` with the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print 'test';
```

uploaded it to my shared hosting with Linux where PERL is enabled and changed my PERL file permissions to 755 via cPanel file manager.

But when I follow by the link like `mydomain.com/test.pl`, I receive the "500 Internal Server Error".

In the "Errors" section of my cPanel I see just the line

> uid: (1639/uahst341) gid: (1641/uahst341) cmd: test.pl

where `uahst341` is the current user of cPanel

I don't have the access to the command line. Can I and how to run the file without the command line prompt?

**UPDATED**

With the help of my hosting provider I found out that I must to create PERL file inside of `/cgi-bin` folder, type a code via cPanel File manager and add the line like `print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";` However, when I write the same code in Notepad++ in UTF-8 and then upload the file to the server, I again receive the 500 error and see that uploaded file has 2 bytes more than created via File manager (in UTF-8). So there is a problem with the encoding. Which exactly?

Comment: What is your goal here? Are you trying to create a Perl-based website (CGI), or are you trying to learn Perl in general?

Comment: I just need an environment to test some code in PERL with MySQL

Comment: Have you considered installing Perl on your own computer? Does your cPanel have any kind of "error log" or "CGI log"?

Comment: The only "error log" I found is the Errors section of cPanel I mentioned in the question

Comment: Are the line endings set to \r\n in Notepad++?

Comment: Yes, I've replaced \r\n\ with \n and resolved the problem, thanks

Comment: Your extra 2 characters might be a byte order mark (BOM), and I wouldn't be surprised if that disrupted the shells ability to parse the `#!` line at the beginning, so it never gets to perl.

Comment: If your file has a BOM, this will show you how to remove it:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20617241/2109800

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your file is being run, and the problem is that it doesn't output a valid HTTP response?  I'd fix that first, though I'm not sure if the file is being run or not.

This is close to the minimal response:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
print "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
print "\r\n";
print "test\r\n";
```

Use of env in the first line is optional, but makes your code more general and is a good habit.

You can usually count on your web server to do a few bits for you, so a slightly simpler version would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";
print "test\n";
```

It is good to start using suitable libraries as soon as you are ready for them.  Have a look at https://perlmaven.com/hello-world-with-plain-cgi for some sample code.  If you've done a bit in other languages and are familiar with object oriented concepts, then you should probably start with CGI::Simple in perl.

If your perl script isn't being executed at all, then you need to know a bit about how the web server is configured.  The web server (e.g. it might be apache or nginx) needs to see the `.pl` suffix and know to run the file with perl.  It might or might not be configured that way.  It might be that it wants you to use a `.cgi` suffix, or you might need to put the file in a `/cgi-bin/` directory at the top of your site.  If your not sure, then ask your hosting provider.

Comment: Regarding e.g. `Content-Type: text/plain\n\n`, for basic [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) scripts, some variation of this line has to be sent regardless of language (so in e.g. C++ or Python as well). Also, another common type to return is `Content-type: text/html` for HTML content.